# calling function in shared lib file with no symbol table

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have a .so lib file that is not written by me. 
this is on a QNX arm-le system with eclipse as ide.

If i open the file with ida pro , i can see a lot of exported functions.

I want to call one of these functions.

I tried :

```
    handle = dlopen ("/tmp/lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
       fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
       exit(1);
    }

    cosine = dlsym(handle, "cos");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
```

That gives

```
unknown symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
unknown symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
unknown symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE
unknown symbol: _ZTISt9exception
Unresolved symbols
```

Comment: It looks like the library relies on some other external libraries that are not being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is quite clearly the ([mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B)) name of a C++ symbol, which implies that the library you're trying to use was written in C++. You should try linking your program against the standard C++ runtime library.

Answer (score 2):

You are not distinguishing between `dlopen` and `dlsym` errors (you should).

The error you get is from `dlopen`, and it means that `/tmp/lib.so` has dependency on  your standard C++ runtime library (usually `libstdc++.so`) symbols, but was not itself linked against `libstdc++.so`.

To fix this, you must make `libstdc++.so` available, by either

- linking your test program with `g++` instead of `gcc`, or adding `-lstdc++` to the link line, or
- calling `dlopen("libstdc++.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)` before trying to `dlopen` `/tmp/lib.so`.